# Find theme's name

Tags: gnome, themes, icon-themes

[image: Ubuntu theme]

Hello, who knows what is this theme name?

Comment: Where did you find this image?

Comment: @anwar grrrrrrrrrr :+

Comment: @OwenHines - Well, judjing from the watermark, I think he has found it on the Softpedia website (http://www.softpedia.com/).

Comment: @CristianaNicolae There are many places where stock watermark images can be re-uploaded. I just wanted to know the context of where he saw it.

Comment: After seeing the "clues" in the photo, I've searched on Google for the terms: marius nestor softpedia snapcraft. And I have found this exact photo. It was posted 4 days ago on Softpedia website along with an article about Snapcraft. So, I guess this is the context the OP found the photo:  http://news.softpedia.com/news/canonical-announces-snapcraft-2-19-snappy-creator-tool-for-ubuntu-16-04-lts-509044.shtml#sgal_0 @OwenHines

Comment: So I think that the OP likes to keep himself up-to-date regarding the IT news, and one of the sources  he consults might be Softpedia. Although, there are (quite few) possibilities that he may have found the image someplace else (maybe on the Softpedia Facebook page ;-) ) @OwenHines

Comment: @OwenHines, i found this at [link](http://news.softpedia.com/news/canonical-announces-snapcraft-2-19-snappy-creator-tool-for-ubuntu-16-04-lts-509044.shtml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theme in the image is Adapta theme. You can install it from Adapta themes PPA https://launchpad.net/~tista/+archive/ubuntu/adapta or if you want from theme's github project page https://github.com/tista500/Adapta. PPA way will be the easiest.

Add the PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tista/adapta
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the theme with this command

```
sudo apt-get install adapta-gtk-theme
```

---

I noticed that you tagged the question with [icon-themes](/questions/tagged/icon-themes) too! The icon theme in question is Faba Icon theme and can be installed from Noobslab Icon theme PPA.

Add the PPA and update package index using these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/icons
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the icon theme using this command

```
sudo apt-get install faba-icon-theme
```